# dropbox datastore tables do not show up on uninstall and reinstall

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am creating some tables from my android app on dropbox using datastore api.

Suppose I inserted some data in tables. I did call sync() and data is visible in `browse datastores` in app console. But when I uninstalled app and reinstalled it, and try to find if user has any existing data from this app. It never shows up . `store.getTables()` is just returning nothing.

My intent is to be able to import any existing data from app during re-installation.

Sample Code:
In first installation,

```
DbxDatastore store = manager.openDefaultDatastore();
DbxTable table1 = store.getTable("table1");
table1.insert().set("name","test");
store.sync();
```

After above step, table1 shows 1 record in `browse datastores` in app console. Now if I uninstall app and reinstall it, I want to read that 1 record which exists in datastore.

```
DbxDatastore store = manager.openDefaultDatastore();
Set<DbxTable> tablesList = store.getTables();
```

Here getTables() does not return anything. Even if I call store.sync() before calling getTables(), it returns nothing.

How can I import existing data upon re-installation of app ?

Android SDK version: 4.4.2 and 4.3 with dropbox sync and datastore api

Comment: This should "just work," so you may have to give us more details, like what SDK (if any) you're using, maybe some code. A random guess is that you're looking for this data before the app has had a chance to do its initial sync with the server, but that's just a guess.

Comment: did you find any solution ..facing the same probb??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my comment is correct. You're calling `getTables` immediately after opening the datastore, so no data has been downloaded yet. That means you're looking purely at what's been cached locally (and for an account that was just linked, nothing will be cached locally yet.)

You should add a listener to the datastore and wait for its status to indicate a sync has completed. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxDatastoreStatus. I believe you'll want to wait for `isDownloading` to be false for the first time.

That said, typically you'll just set a listener that will update your UI any time something changes... do you really need to do something special when the account is first linked versus any other change?

Comment: Suppose if I add listener to datastore and listen for all incoming changes, and then call getTables(). What is usual response-time ? Because on re-installing, I want to load app with existing data.

Comment: It depends on the size of the datastore (and, of course, whether or not you have an internet connection). It should be whatever the time is that it takes to download that much data.

Comment: When account is first linked, I wanted user to give an option of importing existing data. But it takes too much time just to know whether there is table in datastore i.e. getTables() result is empty.

Comment: Just checked for isDownloading to be false. Even after it becomes false, getTables() return nothing.

Comment: Did you call `sync` once `isDownloading` becomes false?